# Wordpress redirect to main host

Tags: wordpress, cloudflare-workers

I am looking for a WP php rule to always serve any webpage via the desired host without adding a redirect rule which is not an option in this case. see below.

We have our main site on one server and a WordPress installed on another server. We use cloudflare workers to serve the blogs content (blog.domain) via a subdirectory of the main server (domain.com/blog).

To avoid some issues on the admin side of WP we had to modify the wp-config.php to specify the correct host which would be the main domain/blog

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = '/blog' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] = '/blog' . $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];
$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] = '/blog' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] = 'www.domain.com';
```

source: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/36201#comment:17

What I noticed afterward is that (1) WP admin will always redirect the subdomain to the desired host, so if I go to the wp admin panel via the original subdomain it will redirect to the main-domain/blog/wp-admin.
( 2) Even when I hit a front end URL and I am logged in to the WP admin the same will happen, the host will be replaced.
(3) if I am not logged in to the admin panel but I am using a URL with a query parameter such as

```
https://sub.domain.com/?page_id=3
```

it will redirect to the desired host with the clean URL.

My question is how can I get WP to always redirect to the desired host? Using a simple redirect rule in PHP or apache/Nginx will result in an infinite loop (since the sub-directory is relying on the subdomain for the content)